# How to add two consecutive Display syntax in the ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to add two consecutive Display syntax in the ViewModel?

Display Name :  List the available storage units

```
[Display(Name = "Bottle")]
    public bool IsBottle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Container")]
    public bool IsContainer { get; set; }
```

Both these 2 bool variable will be a check box. In the actual requirement, we have around 4 check box.
For all those 4 check boxes,i will have to have a group header.

Display Name :  List the available storage units

Expected :

```
[Display(Name = "List the available storage units:")]
[Display(Name = "Bottle")]
    public bool IsBottle { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Container")]
    public bool IsContainer { get; set; }
```

Comment: What do you mean _two consecutive Display syntax_?

Comment: Are you asking how to apply the DisplayAttribute twice to a single model property?

Comment: I made the changes in the question ..

Comment: You can't (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) - the `AllowMultiple=false` flag means the attribute cannot be repeated.

Comment: is there a way to achieve this ? as a work around

Comment: What is it that you want to display in the view?

Comment: yes sir .. that specific row of record ... has check boxes..  such as Yes , No, Yes & No .. ..  For these 4 check boxes, we need a group label

Comment: You could add another property to the model to act as the 'group' heading (its difficult to visualize what you want to do when you do not show the view code)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need display header for grouped checkbox? yes.

Using custom attributes :

Custom attribute example

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property| AttributeTargets.Constructor)]
public class GroupHeader : System.Attribute
{
        public string Title = "";

        public GroupHeader()
        {
        }

        public GroupHeader(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
}
```

We can use below another display(group header) name

```
[GroupHeader("List the available storage units:")]
[Display(Name = "Bottle")]
public bool IsBottle { get; set; }
```